# print value on console

Tags: shell

Looking for solution round this .

i have a script

```
a.bsh

#!/bin/bash
a=5
echo $a
```

this prints 5 when ever executed .

> ./a.bsh
> 5

i need to either look to update this script or use another away to get value 5 when i do on console

> echo $a

i tried updating .bashrc with

```
alias a=5
```

but it didnt work . Also we can use `set` in this somehow ?

please advice

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Is the value always 5? Do you just need a variable that holds the number 5? Why do you need a script that all it does it printing a constant number? Have you tried `export a=5`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to echo the value which you provide via command line you can use something like:

```
./a.bsh 5
```

and the script itself:

```
#! /bin/sh -
printf '%s\n' "$1"
```

Also remember:

- [parameter expansions must be quoted in `sh` / `bash`](/q/68694)
- no need for `bash` for such a simple script, using `sh` makes it more portable (to systems that don't have `bash` or don't have it in `/bin`) and likely more efficient.
- [`echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data](/q/65803/).

Comment: Don't teach beginners bad practices, always quote a variable unless you unless you really understand how word-splitting in shell works.

Comment: Can you help with what you actually mean by word-splitting here ?

Comment: @Machine, you can check this Q/A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary